# How can I display two shapes instead of one by using C++ OpenGL Glut?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I started to use OpenGL / glut for C++ and I am stuck on being able to display two objects in the window rather than one. So, for the first shape it draws a house-like shape with a square and triangle on the top, with anti-aliasing. The second shape, is supposed to be the same, but does not have anti-aliasing. For now, the second shape just has two dots as opposed to the entire shape. When I have both of the `withoutAntiAliasing` and `withAntiAliasing` methods inside of the void `render()` method, only one shows. How exactly can I make it so that both of the methods described can be shown in the window? Code is below:

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 250.0, 0.0, 250.0);
}

void withAntiAliasing()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2i(155, 150);
    glVertex2i(125, 125);
    glVertex2f(108.5, 162);
    glVertex2f(136, 185);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2i(100, 155.9);
    glVertex2f(145, 192.5);
    glVertex2i(115, 185);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void withoutAntiAliasing()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2i(170, 170);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2i(150, 150);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}

void render()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    withoutAntiAliasing();
    withAntiAliasing();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutCreateWindow("Hey");

    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw lines, you must use [Line primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) instead of [Point primitives](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Point_primitives).
The first mesh is not displayed because you clear the framebuffer before drawing the second mesh.

Move `glClear` and `glFlush` in the `render` function and use the primitive type `GL_LINE_LOOP`:

```cpp
void withAntiAliasing()
{
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2i(155, 150);
    glVertex2i(125, 125);
    glVertex2f(108.5, 162);
    glVertex2f(136, 185);
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2i(100, 155.9);
    glVertex2f(145, 192.5);
    glVertex2i(115, 185);
    glEnd();
}

void withoutAntiAliasing()
{
    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2i(170, 170);
    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glVertex2i(150, 150);
    glEnd();
}

void render()
{
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    withoutAntiAliasing();
    withAntiAliasing();

    glFlush();
}
```